# jquery css change focuses the element - how to do it quietly?

Tags: jquery, css

When I change css of an element that has been scrolled past, the view jumps to that div (by scrolling up) when I apply css changes using .css(...) It can be something as simple as changing background-color.

Is there a way around? I just want it to quietly make the changes in the background instead of jumping to that div.

```
...other stuff...

<div style="position: absolute">

<div style="position: relative;" id = "myDiv"></div>

</div>


...other stuff...



 <div id="myButton">
            <h2>Click here</h2>
          </div>

$("#myButton").click(function () { $("#myDiv").css("background-color", "yellow");}
```

Actually it doesn't matter what object I change background-color on. It can be myDiv or anything. If it has been scrolled past, it'll jump to that object, and then come back to the right div.

**Guys, close this question. As you guys mentioned, it had nothing to do with changing css at all.**

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. `.css()` does NOT affect position on page. Maybe show you code?

Comment: @Martijn it does go back to the correct position, but first it jumps to the div that has been scrolled past...and then returns to the correct position.

Comment: Oh, I see you have a button. Thats the trigger up :) Again, `css()` does not do that kind of behaviour

Comment: @Martijn, so the button is causing it to trigger up? The button is in view/viewport... but this div in question is not.

Comment: does your button have a href="" on it and if so does it have something like a # in it? I'm thinking if it did that can sometimes cause browser windows to jump. It would probably help to see your button markup and the function you are calling on click, if you please.

Comment: @StaceyGarrison No, it doesn't. I'll try too give more information.

Comment: We're gonna need more code to fix this one. As was said above, .css doesn't cause window scroll on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   $(document).ready(function(){       
                var scroll_pos = 0;
                $(document).scroll(function() { 
                    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                    if(scroll_pos > 210) {
                        $("your div").css('background-color', 'blue');
                    } else {
                        $("your div").css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: No, I did not need help with how to change background color after scrolling. I already know at what point I'm supposed to change the background-color. Please see my edit and comment.